# Downloading image via POST does not work on mobile browsers. How to fix?

Tags: html, image, mobile, download

My downloading idea for my website works for desktop browsers but not for mobile devices. When mobile users select the download button, the download button begins then fails, yet the connection to the server is always excellent.

This is the HTML I created to produce the download button:

```
<form method="POST" action="imageno/downloadimage">
<input type="submit" value="Download image">
</form>
```

I make it so that users MUST click the button to initiate the download. Anyone who accesses the link without clicking will receive an error with a 410 status code. Also, when the download begins, the following headers are sent to the browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 04:01:41 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
cache-control: max-age=864000,must-revalidate
Last-Modified: Wed, 03 Dec 2014 05:00:00 GMT
content-disposition: attachment; filename="HQ_Photo10.jpg"
Content-Length: 165621
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=10
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

I also tested the requests via CURL and everything seems to work there.

What can I do to make this work for mobile browsers? Do I need to change the headers in some way?

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the browser is making a SECOND request to the download via the GET method after first requesting it via the POST method. Here's proof:

```
[09/Dec/2015:23:27:43 -0500]  POST /bloke/2015dec05/21/DL HTTP/1.1  200  211401  http://pictures.m.clubcatcher.com/bloke/2015dec05/21  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.2; en-ca; SGH-T589R Build/FROYO) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
[09/Dec/2015:23:27:44 -0500]  GET /bloke/2015dec05/21/DL HTTP/1.1  410  49  -  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.2; en-ca; SGH-T589R Build/FROYO) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

Is there any way I can keep the GET request method disabled and send some special header to mobile browsers or something? I want them to be able to download the file without requesting it again using GET.

Comment: What kind of mobile? Have you bothered to use a debugger and check for errors and/or the network response details? https://www.google.ca/search?q=how+to+debug+mobile+chrome https://www.google.ca/search?q=how+to+debug+mobile+safari

Comment: I'm using an older android on wifi. Other people have download issues with specifically android OS's.

Comment: I updated my question. See above.